# Data binding with ASP.NET and custom Data Objects

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

If I bind a control in page markup to a custom object:

```
myPageControl.DataSource = myCustomObject
myPageControl.DataBind()
```

In what way(s) can I access the properties or fields of the custom object in the markup for data binding? I've seen this expression:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "myCustomProperty") %>
```

But it's fairly long, and somewhat verbose. Is there an easier way to bind to properties inside objects, or is this the only way? I've seen everything from:

```
<%# myCustomProperty %>
```

or

```
<#= myCustomProperty %>
```

or

```
<%# Eval(myCustomProperty) %>
```

So... what's the difference here? Is there some reference somewhere that explains everything you can do between `<%# ... %>` tags? I guess I'm just looking for a shorter way to bind to my properties than what I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are all sorts of different inline tags, so take a look **[here](http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-%283c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc%29.aspx)**

**update:** you see mixed notations of ASP.NET 1.1, 2.0 and 3.5

perhaps you should read **[this tutorial](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/040630.htm)**

Comment: If you scroll down on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx), there is actually no example or reference for the `DataBinder.Eval(...)`, which is partially why I asked this question.